# Getting the Xpath of a span web element

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML code:

[image]

I need to refer to the span element (last element in the tree) in order to check if it exists.
The problem is, I can't find the right XPath to it and was not able to find any question already concerning this specific issue.

I tried:

```
"//span[@data-highlighted='true']"
```

and also further successional XPaths referring to its previous nodes but was not able to actually get a working Xpath. The difficulty for me is that it has no id or title so I tried to get it through its "data-highlighted" but that does not seem to work.

Just for the sake of completeness:
I have written the following Java method which is meant to get an Xpath as its input:

```
public Boolean webelementIsPresent (String inputXpath) throws InterruptedException {
return driver.findElements(By.xpath(inputXpath)).size()>0;
}
```

Then in a test class I perform an assertTrue wether the webelement exists (the method returns a True) or wether it doesn't.

I'm open for any help, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: why not search for span which contains that text

Comment: Just tried "//span[@data-highlighted='true']" myself, and chrome devtools finds the element without any problems. Your XPath should be correct. Can you find other elements without issues?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can get element by text

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Willkommen')]"));
```

Or find `div` with `id` and based on that, find span element. There are 2 options to do that:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='description']//span"));
```

OR

```
WebElement descriptionDiv = driver.findElement(By.id("description"));
descriptionDiv.findElement(By.tagName("span"));
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#description span"));
```

Comment: Your last code block would be better as a single CSS selector, `#description span`, since it would only require hitting the page once instead of chaining .`findElement`s.

Comment: @JeffC I totally agree. However, my point was to present different way of finding Web Elements to OP :)

I will add you suggestion as additional option to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To identify the element `"//span[@data-highlighted='true']"` you can use the following `xpath` :

```
"//table[@class='GJBYOXIDAQ']/tbody//tr/td/div[@class='GJBYOXIDPL' and @id='descriptionZoom']/table/tbody/tr/td/div[@class='GJBYOXIDIN zoomable highlight' and @id='description']/div[@class='gwt-HTML' and @id='description']//span[@data-highlighted='true']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath looks fine, my guess is that it's a timing issue and you need a brief wait. It could also be that the page was in a certain state when you captured the HTML and it's not always in that state when you reach the page.

There are other locators that should work here.

XPath

```
//span[contains(., 'Willkommen')]
```

CSS selectors (These may or may not work based on your current XPath results)

```
span[data-highlighted='true']
#description span[data-highlighted='true']
```

For your function, I would suggest a change. Replace the `String` parameter with a `By` for more flexibility. You can then locate an element using any method and not be restricted to just XPath.

```
public Boolean webElementIsPresent(By locator)
{
    return driver.findElements(locator).size() > 0;
}
```

or if you want to add a wait,

```
public Boolean webElementIsPresent(By locator)
{
    try
    {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
        return true;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```